# how i recover data from firebase to android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want read data, to build a object that I can display for my project.

[image: database]

```
public class Curp{

  public String curpGen, Nombre, ApPat, apMat, sexo, estado, fecha;

  public Curp(String  curpGen,String Nombre,String ApPat,String apMat,String fecha,String sexo,String estado){
    this.curpGen=curpGen;
    this.Nombre=Nombre;
    this.ApPat=ApPat;
    this.apMat=apMat;
    this.fecha=fecha;
    this.sexo=sexo;
    this.estado=estado;
  }

}
```

In this part, I have the methods to read the data and save to create the object curp.

I want know how build the object `Curp` with data.

```
 database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String curpGen=dataSnapshot.getValue(Curp.class).curpGen.toString();
            String nombre=dataSnapshot.getValue(Curp.class).Nombre.toString();
            String ApPat=dataSnapshot.getValue(Curp.class).ApPat.toString();
            String ApMat=dataSnapshot.getValue(Curp.class).apMat.toString();
            String Fecha=dataSnapshot.getValue(Curp.class).fecha.toString();
            String sexo=dataSnapshot.getValue(Curp.class).sexo.toString();
            String edo=dataSnapshot.getValue(Curp.class).estado.toString();

            Curp value=new Curp(curpGen,nombre,ApPat,ApMat,Fecha,sexo,edo);
            lista.add(value);
            cupadapter=new CurpAdapter(lista);
            reciclador.setAdapter(cupadapter);
        }
 }
```

> 22:33:01.533 13269-13269/com.example.montero.softtimcurpmontero
>   E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout 10-10
>
> 22:33:01.763 13269-13269/com.example.montero.softtimcurpmontero
>   E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout 10-10
>
> 22:33:01.953 13269-13269/com.example.montero.softtimcurpmontero
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.montero.softtimcurpmontero, PID: 13269
>   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.example.montero.softtimcurpmontero.Curp is missing a constructor with no arguments

Comment: It looks like you already have the basics for recovering/retrieving data. Which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: to recover the info and buil the object Curp, but the 2nd code not works, the code fails

Comment: When the app crashes there should be an error and stack trace in the logcat. Please edit you question to include that information.

Comment: make one empty constructor in side Crup model class and initialize it before setting your adapter in to recyclerview.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use that constructor. You can assign values to variables if the variable name are same as the firebase node values.
Try this:

```
database.limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Curp value=dataSnapshot.getValue(Curp.class);
                    //Use this object
                }
            });
```

Comment: die at Curp value=dataSnapshot.get value (Curp.class) com.example.montero.softtimcurpmontero.MainActivity$1.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:48)

Comment: Curp is missing a constructor with no arguments

Comment: if my answer helped you, please upvote it. I answered to  Your first question (before update)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that i need was build a empty condtructor in class Curp an Curp value in MainActivity

```
database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Curp value=new Curp();
            value=dataSnapshot.getValue(Curp.class);
            lista.add(value);
            cupadapter=new CurpAdapter(lista);
            reciclador.setAdapter(cupadapter);
        }
```

}